# Tiling of squares in instances of Pythagoras Theorem

Tags: geometry, tiling

The Pythagorean Theorem (PT) states that in a right triangle, the square on the hypotenuse equals the sum of the squares on the legs or $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$.

Is there an instance of PT (a given $a$, $b$ and $c$) where there exists a tiling of all three squares in congruent shapes?

Well, yes, there is one, where $a = b$:

[image: pythagorean theorem tiled where a = b]

where it is easy to count the smaller triangles in each square by inspection and add $8 + 8 = 16$. The tiles only happen to be similar to the original triangle.

I am curious if there is one where $a < b$, or a proof (or proof idea) that one cannot exist. The tiles can be similar to the triangle or not, as long as they are all congruent. The idea is to give a simple verification of the single PT instance by counting the tiles.

Comment: I'm a little confused - as per the answer below, isn't in fact just the tiling of the $a\times a$ square by $a^2$ $1\times1$ squares, etc., such a tiling by congruent shapes?  Or are you looking for such a tiling with a finite number of shapes, or one that works for arbitrary real $a$ (which seems unlikely given the nature of the problem)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a given Pythagorean triangle with shorter leg $a$ (e.g., vertical) and longer leg $b$ you could build a grid composed by small right triangles with legs $\frac{1}{b}, \frac{1}{a}$. These small triangles are similar to the initial triangle because the ratio between the smaller and the longer leg is $\frac{\frac{1}{b}}{\frac{1}{a}}=\frac{a}{b}$. Each pair of these small triangles forms a small $\frac{1}{b} \cdot \frac{1}{a}$ rectangle, and arranging $ab$ of these rectangles in $b$ rows and $a$ columns (with the rectangles having the smaller side $\frac{1}{b}$ in the vertical direction) we can get a unitary square. In such a grid, each unitary square contains $2ab$ triangular tiles that are similar to the original triangle, and all three squares built on the sides of the initial triangle (including that drawn from the hypothenuse) contain an integer, countable number of tiles. The following image shows an example for the Pythagorean triangle $3,4,5$, where the small triangles have legs $1/4$ and $1/3$, respectively, and where the unitary square contains $3\cdot4=12$ small rectangles and $24$ small triangles.

[image: 345 tiling]

Another example that shows how to tile the square on the hypotenuse in a way that is easy to confirm is an accurate tiling and is the correct sum.

[image: 12sqrt(5)]

The triangle is 1, 2, $\sqrt{5}$. The tiles are all of size 1/2, 1, $\sqrt{5}/2$. The smaller square is 1x1, the larger is area 4, and the square on the hypotenuse is area 5 by adding the unit square in the middle, and four of the area 1 triangles around.

This tiling has the basic idea of a proof of the full general PT using the algebraic identity: 
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
{\rm the\ sum\ of\ the\ areas\ of\ the\ two\ leg\ squares} && a^2 + b^2\\
{\rm the\ center\ full\ unit\ squares}  &=& (a−b)^2\\
{\rm the\ areas\ of\ the\ 4\ triangles}  & & + 4 (a b)/2\\
{\rm the\ area\ of\ the\ square\ on\ the\ hypotenuse} &=& c^2
\end{array}
$$

But the point to the tiling is that the area of the square on the hypotenuse, without such a nice tiling (or a proof of PT) is inscrutable because you can't just 'see' that the areas sum just right (how does your eye cut up the pieces). The tiling here allows you to at least count the tiles, presumably a more trustworthy operation than eye-balling the area.

Comment: That tiles the triangle, but how does a 1/a,1/b triangle (or rectangle) tile an a by a square (and similarly b by b square). I think I see it but am not sure. Also, how do they tile the square on the hypotenuse? I don't see that at all. Can you draw a picture?

Comment: Hi, I added a figure to better clarify my answer.

Comment: Nice. But is there a way to rearrange the tiling of the 5x5 so that it is obvious that it works (without assuming PT)? Say by filling the 5x5 with filings of 4 3x4s and a single unit (also tiled with the mini triangles).

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not believe that it is possible... For example, we cannot fill the 5x5 square with four 3x4 triangles and a single unit square.

Comment: I think you can. You can tile the unit(ary) square as you've done in your picture. Also in your picture, the original 345 triangle is tiled. Rearrange 4 copies of the original triangle around the unit square to get the square on the hypotenuse, with all the mini-tiles axis-aligned. I don't have a good drawing program. What did you use? The smallest nontrivial one works with a = 1, b = 4, c = $\sqrt{5}$ all with 1/2, 1, $\sqrt{5}/2$ tiles.

Comment: Yes, you are right, of course if we allow the tiles to have different  orientations within the $5\cdot5$ square you can arrange the four $4\cdot3$ triangles with the unit square in the central position. I simply used Power Point to draw the picture.

Comment: Anatoly, yes, eight possible orientations of the tile are allowed. Essentially so you can look at the picture and say "Yes, this is a correct tiling" and then just count tiles to see that they add up.

Comment: Anatoly, see my new image. This is the tiling I'm thinking of. In your tiling, the tiling of the square on the hypotenuse is 'inscrutable', you can't tell what the size and orientation of the tiles in it are.

Comment: Very nice, Mitch, this shows that a simple tiling can also be obtained for many non-Pythagorean triangles (i.e., right triangles where the sides are not all integer), in particular those where legs are integer and the hypothenuse is not.

Comment: This is almost good enough for a very basic class in geometry. The only 'hard' part is that A + B = 90. But the smart ones in class should be able to see that has the basic idea of a proof of the full general PT using the algebraic identity $a^2 + b^2$ (the sum of the areas of the two leg squares) $ = (a-b)^2$ (the center full unit squares)  $ + 4 (a b)/2 $ (the areas of the 4 triangles) $ = c^2$ (the area of the square on the hypotenuse)

Comment: Another beautiful (and elegant) proof of the PT.

Comment: Anatoly: proof #3 at http://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/ OK, #4 too.